# make/gcc/clang looking for file with a blank filename, gives error

Tags: gcc, makefile, clang

I have OSX 10.11.4, Xcode 7.3.1. 
Using `make --` calls `gcc --` calls `clang`, I get this error where clang is looking for a file whose name is a space!

```
Make error 1: clang: error: no such file or directory: ' '.
```

That is a space!

I have no idea how to fix this. The makefile formatting is correct.
Here is the end of the output from make:

```
gcc -g -v -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/m/BioPrep \
      -o mod \
      ../mshell/runit0.o \
      ../mshell/tline.o \
      ../mshell/getshm.o \
      ../mshell/callLSODA.o \
      ../mshell/extras.o \
      ../mshell/nrutil.o \
      ../mshell/exten.o \
      ../choosedisp/choosedisp_main.o \
      ../choosedisp/choosedisp_cb.o \
      ../choosedisp/choosedisp_fm.o \
      ../connectdisps/connectdisps.o \
      ../connectdisps/opwsock.o \
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

clang: error: no such file or directory: ' '

make: *** [mod] Error 1
```

======================= Here is the contents of the Makefile:

```
# This is Makefile with all graphics code removed so that a compilation of mod can proceed
#  "MakefileA" has the graphics files present but commented (#) out
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -v -Wall
INCL = -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/Users/prowat/BioPrep
LIBS = -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -lX11 -lforms


mod: model.o \
     ../mshell/runit0.o \
     ../mshell/tline.o \
     ../mshell/getshm.o \
     ../mshell/callLSODA.o \
     ../mshell/extras.o \
     ../mshell/nrutil.o \
     ../mshell/exten.o \
     ../choosedisp/choosedisp_main.o \
     ../choosedisp/choosedisp_cb.o \
     ../choosedisp/choosedisp_fm.o \
     ../connectdisps/connectdisps.o \
     ../connectdisps/opwsock.o \
     ../lsoda/liblsoda.a`  
        cd ../mshell; make objs`  
        cd ../choosedisp; make objs`  
        cd ../connectdisps; make objs`  
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) \
          -o mod \
          ../mshell/runit0.o \
          ../mshell/tline.o \
          ../mshell/getshm.o \
          ../mshell/callLSODA.o \
          ../mshell/extras.o \
          ../mshell/nrutil.o \
          ../mshell/exten.o \
          ../choosedisp/choosedisp_main.o \
          ../choosedisp/choosedisp_cb.o \
          ../choosedisp/choosedisp_fm.o \
          ../connectdisps/connectdisps.o \
          ../connectdisps/opwsock.o \
          model.o \
          -L../lsoda -llsoda \
          $(LIBS) \
          -lm
```

=====================

Comment: "The makefile formatting is correct" -- and yet it doesn't work. Please include your makefile if you'd like any help.

Comment: You have an extra space at the end of one of your lines, after the backslash.  There can be no space after the backslash: the newline must come immediately after the backslash.

Comment: I checked for those spaces, and for the tabs.

Comment: @Ismail Badawi: I've added the Makefile

Comment: Thank you, MadScientist. I double checked and triple checked for those spaces -- also before posting -- and still managed to miss one. Hard to believe I missed it for so long. So now my problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Please use proper formatting: for code blocks, indent by 4 spaces.  The backticks are only used for fixed-width fonts inside normal text.

You may have looked for spaces, but you need to look again.  Based on the output make has shown you versus your makefile, it's pretty clear that there is at least one space after the backslash at the end of this line:

```
      ../connectdisps/opwsock.o \
```

You can tell this because if there were no spaces after this backslash then it would be continuing to the next line and make whould show the rest of the compile line:

```
      model.o \
      -L../lsoda -llsoda \
      $(LIBS) \
      -lm
```

Since those lines are missing from the output make provided, you can be sure that there's something about the `opwsock.o` line which is preventing make from recognizing the backslash/newline at the end.